# Blitting in new x position Pygame

Tags: python, random, pygame, blit

Im writing a basic mouse dodge game and i need to blit little stars to dodge. i made it so that once one star leaves the screen it blits it again at the top> that works but it blits it in the same x position

Here is the update code that moves the star:

```
def update(self):
    self.mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    (self.player_r.x, self.player_r.y) = self.mouse_pos

    self.star_r.x = ran_x
    self.star_r.y += 2
    if self.star_r.y > 640:
        self.star_r.y = 0
```

Here is where the star gets blitted:

```
def blitPlayer(self, screen):
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(self.player,(self.mouse_pos))
    screen.blit(self.star,(ran_x, self.star_r.y))
```

I define `ran_x` outside the class at the top like this:

```
ran_x = random.randint(10,470)
```

What i think is happening is that when i run it ran_x is being defined by one random number and then keeping that number but i want it to change each time the star leaves the screen

Thanks in Advance!!

-ChristianCareaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why not recompute ran_x here:

```
if self.star_r.y > 640:
    self.star_r.y = 0
    ran_x = new random number
```

Comment: yeah that should do it do you think there is an easy way to blit like 2 or 3 at a time instead of one

Comment: @Christian Careaga Make `ran_x` an instance variable, not static or global. e.g. each star should be associated with its own value for x co-ordinate, so `star.ran_x`